# fgetc returning unexpected value 49 when 1 is expected

Tags: c, stdio, fgetc

I'm having trouble using the fgetc function to read a value from a file. This is the code I'm using :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int k;

    FILE* rede = fopen("/home/leocal/Desktop/Poli/2018-1/Numérico/EP1/Redes/1_Stevenson/a.txt", "r");

    if (rede == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    k = fgetc(rede);
    if (k!=EOF) {
    printf("printing k : %d",k);
    }

    fclose(rede);

    return 0;
}
```

The file "a.txt" has a single character "1", but `k` receives the value 49.

Comment: `49` is the ascii code of `'1'`. Use `printf("printing k : %c",k);` to print it as character

Comment: As @Eugene-sh points `%d` prints the value of `k` as an integer (i.e. a character's ascii value) if you want it to print the character you should use `%c` ... also read the manual page for `printf`

Comment: Leonardo: Curious, if "a.txt" has a single character "*", what value would you expect `k` to have?

Comment: @chux I hope you have your towel with you.

Comment: Funny thing is going with the votes... I guess it could be a subject for some kind of research...

Comment: @LeonardoCalasans are you still having this problem with `fgetc`?

Answer (score 1):

The description of [`fgetc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) says:

> Returns the **character** currently pointed by the internal file position indicator

You are reading the character '`1`' and then printing it's decimal value value with

```
printf("printing k : %d",k);
```

To  print the value of a character with `printf` use `%c`:

```
printf("printing k : %c",k);
```

You can read more about `printf` and how to format its output [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).